# Rebajar array sumando items y agrupando por mes

Tags: javascript, array

Tengo un array asi:

```
"Year:2017,Mes:8,Suma:0"
"Year:2017,Mes:8,Suma:5"
"Year:2017,Mes:8,Suma:5"
"Year:2017,Mes:8,Suma:0"
```

¿De que forma puedo agrupar por mes y año, suman los datos, para que me quede otro array así?

```
"2017-8", "10"
```

Esto es lo que pruebo:

```js
   let datos = {
    "Year:2017,Mes:8":0,
    "Year:2017,Mes:8":5,
    "Year:2017,Mes:8":5,
    "Year:2017,Mes:8":0,
    };

    console.log( agrupar(datos) ); // 650
    
    function agrupar(datos) {
    
      let sum = 0;
      for (let suma of Object.values(datos)) {
        sum += suma;
      }
    
      return sum;
    }
```

Sé que no es complicado, pero no lo puedo lograr.

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Eso no nos dice nada Hugo, incluye más código para saber que estas haciendo.

Comment: Es que es esto solamente Alberto, hago un array con los datos que puse, done estan todos los años y sus meses, quiero agrupar los datos de ese array por año, mes y sumando el item suma.

Comment: Agregue lo que estoy ejecutando, me da resultado 0, y hasta ahí llego...

Answer (score 0):

Esto:

```
let obj = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "a": 3};
```

viene a ser:

```
Object {a: 3, b: 2}
```

como tu clave se repite siempre, la ultima es 0.